# After change to 13306, Galera logs error: Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'repuser@<master node ID>:3306'

Tags: mysql, galera

Working with Galera 25.3.23 on RHEL 7.3

Galera works good before. After changing the MySQL server port from 3306 to 13306, one of the node report error, after restart:

```
Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'repuser@<IP>:3306' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<IP>' (111 "Connection refused"), Internal MariaDB error code: 2003
```

The other 2 nodes works fine after the restart.

Googled the web, but don't find the way to specify the port number.

Also, if possible, please share the usage of the "repuser" ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like you are using classical async master/slave replication on a galera server. Was this intentional? Galera uses a different replication protocol and master/slave off, or especially between nodes, is odd.

Use [CHANGE MASTER TO](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/change-master-to) to change the master's port.